# Calling a function inside iOS static library from command line

Tags: ios, static-libraries

We have some functions made available to us in iOS static library. There is a header (.h) and the compiled (.a) file. Is there any way that the functions in the static library can be called from a command line ( either OS X, Windows or Linux )? I have researched this for couple of days now and I am starting to doubt if this is even possible? We don't deal with Apple/iOS/xcode environment and the vendor only has this static library. Any hints? If it is possible in anyway I am open to reading any and very documentation but at this time I am in doubt if this is even possible? thanks

While checking out what is possible, I ran this

```
lipo -info libExaNumberCalc.a
```

I ran the above and it says

```
Architectures in the fat file: libExaNumberCalc.a are : i386 armv7 x86_64 arm64
```

Wonder if the above adds any hope?

Comment: An iOS static library is for use on iOS if you are not operating in an iOS environment it is not going to be the correct library for you

Comment: haiz, this vendor has put us in a nightmarish situation :-/ We were told that they would make the libraries available for us but this was the last thing we expected. I am thinking any possibility here ... like being able to "run stuff" in some emulator etc and feed the input ... and get the output. It is basically a bunch of functions for crunching some numbers. I am open to any hackish method for now till we get it sorted with the vendor. They are low on tech and their iOS guys are long gone.

Comment: Is there a way to know if this static library is not just for iOS? I mean I have read that when creating such libraries it is possible to create them to run on different architecture? Is there a way to check this with the .a and header file?

Comment: just saw something ... lipo-info xxx.a file? I guess that will tell which architectures I guess ...

Comment: While I test out other stuff, I ran the above and it says "Architectures in the fat file: libExaNumberCalc.a are : i386 armv7 x86_64 arm64

Comment: It seems your library is prepared to run on device and on simulator. It should build as a standalone executable on Mac just fine (it gives a warning during link stage but it works), I went on and tried it without problems with my openssl static lib. The library file is named "libcrypto.a", -L option gives a hint where to look for library file to the compiler `clang -lcrypto -L/Projects/test -o aa.out main.c`

Comment: Thanks. Can I know what is the -lcrypto among the options/switches? Sorry I am not so familiar with the LLVM C Front-end

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that springs to mind is that you could write thin wrapper around your library function and build/run it. Something like

```
// main.c
#include "your_library_header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // parse & pass parameters if necessary from command line

  your_lib_function();

  return 0;
}
```

Build with something like

```
clang main.c -o output.file -lyourlibrary
```